# Axios response data is always set as empty string in laravel

Tags: laravel, axios, laravel-5.7, laravel-response

I am having some strange problem with axios I never had before, any returned response from laravel backend to vue frontend is empty..

`return response()->json(['message' => 'Success!']);`

This line is just after the post is edited...

I also tried:

```
return response(['message' => 'Success!']);
return ['message' => 'Success!'];
```

And when I `console.log()` response:

```
axios.post(url).then((response)=>{
    console.log(response);
});
```

I get everything about response and data as empty string, I am having this problem in Laravel 5.7 where in 5.6 works just fine...

Comment: Have you ever tried your endpoints before with postman?

Comment: Nope because I am using session based validation.

Comment: Did you set the "X-CSRF-Token" with your requests ? I thinks there's a request validation problem and you get a redirect back (if the token is ok, try to make the request on a non protected route see if that works ).

Answer (score 1):

In you blade make sure you have `csrf_token` in the head

xyz.blade.php

```
<head>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
</head
```

From Vue or React:
Make sure your method is right get, post, delete, put in routes file (`web.php` or anything)

```
axios.post('/some/url', {
           post_param_a : 1, 
            post_param_b : 2
         }).then(response => {
              //your value should be in response.data object
              console.log(response.data.message)
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
```

Inside Controller :

```
public function methodName(){
    return response()->json(['message' => 'Success!']);
}
```

Alternatively you can also debug 
Right click on browser >> Inspect >> Network tab >> Refer to screenshot.

[image]

You can also `dd($response)` your response and view in the inspector in response section